# PL/PGSQL always returns array or list of arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, nearest-neighbor

Given the simple pl/pgsql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (point geometry
                              , OUT _street text
                              , OUT _gid int
                              , OUT distance real)
AS $$
BEGIN 

    SELECT min(distance(point,geom)) as dist, gid, name into distance, _gid, _street
    from streets 
    where geometria && Expand(point,0.001) group by gid, name order by dist limit 1;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

results in something akin to:

```
 geobase=# select foo(GeomFromText('POINT(-99.124191496999 19.3490666368031)',4326));
                      foo                      
 -------------------------------------------------
 ("PASEO DE LOS FRAMBOYANES",345483,0.000118338)
```

Which is fine, except for the fact that I would expect something more akin to this:

```
          _street         |  _gid  |  distance     
--------------------------+--------+-------------
 PASEO DE LOS FRAMBOYANES | 345483 | 0.000118338
```

I have tried variants with the `RETURN` clause, defining it as a rowtype, record and even table, but I always get a tuple or array as indicated in the example. Any clues as to how to have the result in a way similar to a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asked has been answered many times. To decompose the returned row type:

```
SELECT * FROM foo( ... );
```

Like here:

- [How to get individual columns from table returned from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137820/how-to-get-individual-columns-from-table-returned-from-a-function/28137957#28137957)

---

*But there is more.*

Your function with less confusing syntax, less error prone and simplified:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (_point geometry)
  RETURNS TABLE (street text, gid int, distance real)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETRUN QUERY 
   SELECT s.name, s.gid, distance(_point, s.geom)
   FROM   streets s
   WHERE  s.geometria && expand(_point, 0.001)
   ORDER  BY 3
   LIMIT  1;
END
$func$;
```

Since you have `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`, you do not need `min()` and `GROUP BY` at all.

Note how I table-qualified all columns to avoid naming conflicts.

There is ***one subtle difference***: If the query finds ***no row*** your original returns a row with NULL values instead, while my function actually returns no row. Typically, you'll want the latter.

The same as equivalent simple SQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (_point geometry)
  RETURNS TABLE (street text, gid int, distance real)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT s.name, s.gid, distance(_point, s.geom)
FROM   streets s
WHERE  s.geometria && expand(_point, 0.001)
ORDER  BY 3
LIMIT  1;
$func$;
```

Still not very efficient with big tables. You'll be interested in **KNN (k-nearest neighbour) search in PostGis**:

- [Multicolumn index on 3 fields with heterogenous data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658515/multicolumn-index-on-3-fields-with-heterogenous-data-types/22675324#22675324)
- [Improving performance with a Similarity Postgres fuzzy self join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265770/improving-performance-with-a-similarity-postgres-fuzzy-self-join-query/29271972#29271972)

Comment: Thank you very much on your answer. I have an almost irrational repulsion to use numerical parameters, as you do in your example:
    SELECT s.name ... ORDER  BY 3

Is there any kind of advantage in doing so, instead of a more loquacious "ORDER BY distance"?

Comment: @AaronRivacoba: No performance advantage. Just a syntactical shortcut that's particularly convenient for lengthy expressions in the `SELECT` list. Even more so in the example where I don't assign a column alias that has no use otherwise (not visible outside the function). A column alias distance raises the question of possible naming conflicts with the OUT parameter of the function (no conflict in *this* case). You would have to use `distance(_point, s.geom)` **`AS distance`** `... ORDER BY distance`. Relying on an automatic alias seems even less clean.

Answer (score 1):

try `select * from foo(GeomFromText('POINT(-99.124191496999 19.3490666368031)',4326));` ?..

Comment: That works as intended! Thank you very much on your prompt answer.

Comment: @AaronRivacoba If that's the right answer, you should accept it.